# Add date of character class with another date

Tags: r, date

Can we add the date of Character class to another date (lag of specific date). I want to reduce by 05:30:00

```
df
Date
12:48:36
12:48:37
13:48:36
```

Required dateframe

```
df
Date
07:48:36
07:48:37
08:48:36
```

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(1:3, .Label = c("12:48:36", "12:48:37", 
"13:48:36"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Yes. Please provide your dataframe using `dput` and an example of the character date you want to add

Comment: added :)........

Answer (score 1):

You could use `as.ITime` from data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, Date := as.ITime(Date) - as.ITime('05:00:00')]

df
#        Date
# 1: 07:48:36
# 2: 07:48:37
# 3: 08:48:36
```

Edit: If you have stored Date as a factor (as in this example) you need to convert to character first

```
df[, Date := as.character(Date)]
```